# Running Boolean Expressions in Postgres

Tags: ruby, postgresql, psql

I am trying to demonstrate the difference between how ruby and and postgres treat null equality.

For example, in ruby, I run nil == nil and get true. I want to try to run the same type of query in postgres and show that null = null is false, but not sure how to structure it.

Alternatively show that null = null is true and null != null is also true.

Comment: This is not Postgresql feature, but SQL standard one: there are lot of SO answers about NULL = NULL.

Comment: Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29#Comparisons_with_NULL_and_the_three-valued_logic_(3VL)

Answer (score 3):

```
select null = null;
 ?column?
----------

(1 row)
```

It is not false, nor true, but undefined.

Comment: Or, more understandably, `(NULL = NULL) IS NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Almost any evaluation against a null in postgres will return a null (short of some functions like `concat()`). To return a boolean when evaluating a null you have to use `IS NULL`

This will return True: `SELECT NULL IS NULL`

This will return False: `SELECT NULL IS NOT NULL`